# How to improve performance PHP forEach to handle 20K rows at once

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a ticket system (PHP/Laravel+Mongo), and need to check if any actions should be applied. For example, if no activity for 12 hours with a ticket - change status, and send the email notification.

can you share please your experience how to handle around 20K rows from database in foreach loop and do some job for each of them periodically?

For now, I just get all rows from the database and do foreach, and I'm not ok with performance.

**Problem #1. System requirements and server limits**
I'm looking for the pattern for such type of systems, we can imaging that each Task it's a finite machine, and my script is a supervisor that follow for changes and toggle states. Problem is a memory & CPU when I do foreach with 20K items, it's just a wrong way scale up the server with each 1k of items, and it will grow.

**Problem #2. Performance**
Each task require some time for processing it (check state, select next state, do the actions related to next state) and I use queues for time-consumed actions like sending emails/sms/calls. It works normally with a small number of rows, but with 20K rows, I got the delay around 10 minutes for that, and it's crucial.

I thought that I have to use another approach, or maybe tool (maybe nodejs nonblocking) to manage and toggle the states for tasks concurrently.

Thanks

Comment: You could divide your actions in multiple queries. For example, no activity for 12 hours, then update rows where activity > 12 hours. And so on.

Comment: This is hard to answer as it depends on numerous factors, network speed/latency, what data is in the array, etc. Do some tests to see where your bottleneck is. Given you're even asking this question, I'd hazard a guess you'll need to add some good indexes on your table(s).

Comment: There is a plenty of actions that have to be applied to task, and 12 hours it's just an example, in common it's more harder. I have to send emails, check that previous action was performed, make a phone call, send sms and so on. I take 1 task, go through logic and do the job, next take another. One task is a finite machine with predefined states/actions.

Answer (score 1):

What I think would be the best practice in your case is: have a cron run every hour or 12h (Aiming for roundly hours, depending on your needs to be precise or not). The objective of the cron is to query the records that haven't been changed in the last 12h (where date differs between updated_at and datetime now) and you get the results into an array.

With this array (let's say it's 10k records out of 20k), you update them all to another status with a single query. Afterwards, you can get pluck the user_ids from this array in order to find the user email (or you can inner join users to fetch the user email in the first query, avoiding the need of a secundary query) and you setup a queue system. This way, it keeps working in the background, notifying via email, without compromising the rest of the application.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues

Comment: What if the query has joins across 5 tables and a few DBs and none of them have indexes? What if the DB is running on another server half way around the world in a poor internet connection area? Or on an old server with barely any RAM? I know you're just trying to help, but it's impossible to know how to help in this scenario. It's like saying "My car won't start, what's wrong" sure we can make guesses at flat battery, dirty spark plugs, no petrol, etc etc, but it could be 1,000 things.

Comment: James, are you serious right now? I'm talking about 1 query that would max take 300/500ms to fetch data. What if its across the world? Are you saying a query takes 30minutes to execute? What if it's an old server with low ram? Works just fine, as long as the server has the minimum requirements. He's just asking opinions on how to execute his objective

Comment: "*I'm talking about 1 query that would max take 300/500ms to fetch data.*" You can't know how long it takes to fetch data for their specific scenario - network and resources etc. "*He's just asking opinions on how to execute his objective*" not they're not, they are stating they have a problem with performance, and you can't know what the issue is to know what to advise. But I'll step back, maybe you know more than me and know what their bottleneck is :)